# Wagtail: Display a list of child pages inside a parent page

Tags: python, django, wagtail

In Wagtail CMS, I'm trying to create an index page that will display a list of all its child pages along with a featured image associated with each child page.

I have created these two page models in models.py:

```
class IndexPage(Page):
    intro = RichTextField(blank=True)

    content_panels = Page.content_panels + [
        FieldPanel('intro', classname='full'),
    ]

    subpage_types = ['myapp.ItemPage']


class ItemPage(Page):
    representative_image = models.ForeignKey(
        'wagtailimages.Image',
        null=True,
        blank=True,
        on_delete=models.SET_NULL,
        related_name='+'
    )

    body = RichTextField(blank=True)

    promote_panels = Page.promote_panels + [
        ImageChooserPanel('representative_image'),
    ]

    content_panels = Page.content_panels + [
        FieldPanel('body', classname='full'),
    ]
```

In the template index_page.html, I added the following code:

```
<div class="intro">{{ self.intro|richtext }}</div>

{% for page in self.get_children %}
  {{ page.title }}
  {% image page.representative_image width-400 %}
{% endfor %}
```

This displays all of the child page titles, but not the images.  Is it possible to retrieve the image fields for the child pages?

Answer (score 27, accepted):

From the [release notes of wagtail version 1.1](https://github.com/torchbox/wagtail/blob/master/docs/releases/1.1.rst):

> Usually, an operation that retrieves a queryset of pages (such as `homepage.get_children()`) will return them as basic Page instances, which only include the core page data such as title. The `specific()` method (e.g. `homepage.get_children().specific()`) now allows them to be retrieved as their most specific type, using the minimum number of queries.

Therefore you don't need your custom function in the upcoming release 1.1 anymore and you can change your template to:

```
{% for page in self.get_children.specific %}
    {{ page.title }}
    {% image page.representative_image width-400 %}
{% endfor %}
```

At least since version 0.8 the following should work, too, using `specific`:

```
{% for page in self.get_children %}
    {{ page.title }}
    {% image page.specific.representative_image width-400 %}
{% endfor %}
```

Answer (score 6):

I've found this solution:  Add a function child_pages to the IndexPage:

```
class IndexPage(Page):
    intro = RichTextField(blank=True)

    def child_pages(self):
        return ItemPage.objects.live().child_of(self)

    content_panels = Page.content_panels + [
        FieldPanel('intro', classname='full'),
    ]

    subpage_types = ['myapp.ItemPage']
```

And this can be accessed in the template:

```
{% for page in self.child_pages %}
  {{ page.title }}
  {% image page.representative_image width-400 %}
{% endfor %}
```