# Django / WagtailCMS - get attribute (eg body text) of child page using get_context

Tags: python, django, django-templates, wagtail

I'm trying to access the body text of a child page in my Django / Wagtail CMS blog. I can return the child page title, but I don't know how to use that to get the rest of the child page attributes. The parent is IndexPage, and the child is IndexListSubPage. My model is:

```
class IndexPage(Page):
    body = RichTextField(blank=True)
    feed_image = models.ForeignKey(
        'wagtailimages.Image',
        null=True,
        blank=True,
        on_delete=models.SET_NULL,
        related_name='+'
    )

    content_panels = Page.content_panels + [
        FieldPanel('body', classname="full"),
        ImageChooserPanel('feed_image'),
    ]

    def get_context(self, request):
        context = super(IndexPage, self).get_context(request)
        context['sub_pages'] = self.get_children()
        return context

class IndexListSubPage(Page):
    body = RichTextField(blank=True)
    feed_image = models.ForeignKey(
        'wagtailimages.Image',
        null=True,
        blank=True,
        on_delete=models.SET_NULL,
        related_name='+'
    )

    content_panels = Page.content_panels + [
        FieldPanel('body', classname="full"),
        ImageChooserPanel('feed_image'),
    ]
```

I have tried various combinations in my template:

```
{{ sub_pages }} //returns <QuerySet [<Page: Page title here>]>
{{ sub_pages.body }} //returns nothing
```

This returns the page title for the child page, but I also want other attributes, like the body text. Any ideas? I have tried the image template settings from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32429113/wagtail-display-a-list-of-child-pages-inside-a-parent-page) as well - again, I can get the title, but no attributes. The page has both image and body text in the admin interface.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Wagtail: Display a list of child pages inside a parent page](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32429113/wagtail-display-a-list-of-child-pages-inside-a-parent-page)

Comment: I have tried the solutions in that question - I can't get any attributes other than title.

Comment: I'd expect changing `self.get_children()` to `self.get_children().specific()` to solve this - are you sure this doesn't work?

Comment: I realised that I could add the specific() method to the model as well as in the template, as alluded to in the other question. Adding it to the model worked. I'll write it up here anyway, as this is a slightly different slant on the other answer. Thanks @gasman

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got it working by changing the model to include `.specific()`, as suggested by @gasman. The working model is:

```
class ProjectsPage(Page):
body = RichTextField(blank=True)

content_panels = Page.content_panels + [
    FieldPanel('body', classname="full"),
]

def get_context(self, request):
    context = super(ProjectsPage, self).get_context(request)
    context['sub_pages'] = self.get_children().specific()
    print(context['sub_pages'])
    return context
```

And in the template:

```
{% with sub_pages as pages %}
    {% for page in pages %}
         {{ page.title }}
         {{ page.body }}
    {% endfor %}
{% endwith %}
```

The title and the body of the child page are now being rendered.