# How to display the children of a wagtail page

Tags: python, django, wagtail

My requirement sounds simple, but I am struggling to make it work

In my wagtail project I have a BlogListingPage which has many child pages. I am trying to create a list of the children in a web page. Here is my code:

**models.py**

```
class BlogListingPage(Page):    
    ...
    def get_context(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        context = super().get_context(request, *args, **kwargs)
        context['blog_pages'] = BlogDetailPage.objects.live().child_of(self)
        return context


class BlogDetailPage(Page):
    ...    
    blog_listing = models.ForeignKey(BlogListingPage,
                                     on_delete=models.PROTECT,
                                     blank=True,
                                     null=True,)
```

**views.py**

```
def blog(request):
    url = 'blog/blog_listing_page.html'
    context = {'data': BlogListingPage.objects.all()}
    return render(request, url, context)
```

**blog_listing_page.html**

```
{% block content %}
    {% for blog_listing in data %}
        {% for post in blog_listing.blogdetailpage %}
            <a href="{% pageurl post %}">{{ post.blog_title }}</a>
        {% endfor %}
    {% endfor %}
{% endblock content %}
```

I am lost in the fog of the django/wagtail pages/objects/querysets/all()/specific

Can someone please lead me to clear blue water?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Wagtail: Display a list of child pages inside a parent page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32429113/wagtail-display-a-list-of-child-pages-inside-a-parent-page)

Comment: @Psionman: Amen to "I am lost in the fog of the django/wagtail pages/objects/querysets/all()/specific" (+ "views/tags/templates"). Appreciate your question, and the answer you received has helped make the fog here a bit less dense. I'm posting a followup request for clarification in a comment to the answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A couple of suggestions regarding your approach:

1. Having a foreign key from `BlogDetailPage` to `BlogListingPage` is not the Wagtail way to organise parent-child relationships. All `Page` objects already have a tree hierarchy and you should rely on that, otherwise you lose all the built-in tree handling provided by Wagtail.

   You should use the [parent/subpage rules](http://docs.wagtail.io/en/v2.7.1/topics/pages.html#parent-page-subpage-type-rules) to specify how page types can be related to each other. In you case it would look something like:

   ```
   class BlogListingPage(Page):    
       subpage_types = ['myapp.BlogDetailPage']

   class BlogDetailPage(Page):
       parent_page_types = ['myapp.BlogListingPage']
   ```
2. The `get_context()` method on `BlogListingPage` only runs when Wagtail is serving that specific page in a view. It doesn't run when you're iterating over these pages in your `blog` view. In order to access the children there, you need to do something like this:

   ```
   {% for blog_listing in data %}
       {% for post in blog_listing.get_children.live %}
           <a href="{% pageurl post %}">{{ post.blog_title }}</a>
       {% endfor %}
   {% endfor %}
   ```

   i.e., you need to use the `get_children()` method on the page to obtain it's children. `live()` further filters this to exclude unpublished pages. Note that this will only work if the blog posts are children (in the Wagtail page tree sense) of the listing page. `specific()` isn't important here if you're only using the post URL and title - it is relevant if you want to display fields that are part of your model rather than the base `Page` model.

Comment: Thank you. A life saver. Great description of the solution

Comment: Are there any performance considerations as to where you put the call to `get_children()` or its equivalent? The answer shows iteration via a tag in the template, but you could instead override the context in the Page model, [per the Wagtail docs](https://docs.wagtail.io/en/stable/topics/pages.html#customising-template-context) 

        'context['blog_entries'] = BlogPage.objects.child_of(self)
        <br>return context' <br>
and then iterate over 'blog_entries' in the template. Is either approach faster/better?